# Tiwulfx TableControl can't show records

Tags: java, javafx-8

I start using TiwulFX Library. I started expirmenting with TableControl component, i face an issue. I Just did every thing like the Official Guide
http://learn.tiwulfx.panemu.com/#/table-control/a-4, but i can't get this working.

Here is the code for main application

```
public class main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/main.fxml"));

        Parent parent = new AnchorPane();
        try {
            parent = loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Scene sc = new Scene(parent);
        primaryStage.setScene(sc);

        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

the code for mainController

public class mainController implements Initializable {

```
@FXML
private TableControl<Person> tblPerson;

public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    initTable();
}

private void initTable() {


    tblPerson.setController(new tableController());
    tblPerson.setRecordClass(Person.class);

    tblPerson.reload();

}
```

}

the code for tableController

public class tableController extends com.panemu.tiwulfx.table.TableController {

```
@Override
public TableData<Person> loadData(int i, List<TableCriteria> list, List<String> list1, List<TableColumn.SortType> list2, int i1) {


    List<Person> listEmployee = new ArrayList();
    //  listEmployee.add( new Person(1, "Abdo", 25, "email@email.com", LocalDate.now(), false));
    listEmployee.add(new Person(1));

    return new TableData(listEmployee, false, listEmployee.size());


}
```

}

The code for person class

public class Person {
    private Integer id;

```
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Person(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

and the code for fxml file:

```
<?import com.panemu.tiwulfx.table.TableControl?>
<?import com.panemu.tiwulfx.table.TextColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import com.panemu.tiwulfx.table.NumberColumn?>
<AnchorPane fx:controller="mainController" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"
            minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0"
            prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <TableControl fx:id="tblPerson" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0"
                      AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <columns>
                <NumberColumn propertyName="id" text="Id"/>

            </columns>
        </TableControl>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

and finally the StackTrace:

```
juin 21, 2016 4:28:57 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 8.0.60 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.51
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.panemu.tiwulfx.table.TableControl$13.changed(TableControl.java:728)
    at com.panemu.tiwulfx.table.TableControl$13.changed(TableControl.java:725)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:361)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:176)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:142)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewFocusModel.setFocusedCell(TableView.java:3180)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewFocusModel.focus(TableView.java:3223)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewSelectionModel.focus(TableView.java:1994)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewSelectionModel.focus(TableView.java:1986)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.updateDefaultSelection(TableView.java:2885)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.lambda$new$47(TableView.java:2093)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel$$Lambda$77/1585190318.onChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
    at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.addAll(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:102)
    at com.panemu.tiwulfx.table.TableControl.postLoadAction(TableControl.java:1519)
    at com.panemu.tiwulfx.table.TableControl.access$4400(TableControl.java:82)
    at com.panemu.tiwulfx.table.TableControl$LoadDataTask.lambda$new$2(TableControl.java:1829)
    at com.panemu.tiwulfx.table.TableControl$LoadDataTask$$Lambda$128/745079890.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.concurrent.EventHelper.fireEvent(EventHelper.java:219)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task.fireEvent(Task.java:1356)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task.setState(Task.java:723)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.lambda$call$496(Task.java:1434)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable$$Lambda$133/2002617391.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$50/1549514099.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$49/350828698.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/658471308.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils
    at com.panemu.tiwulfx.table.BaseColumn$3.call(BaseColumn.java:135)
    at com.panemu.tiwulfx.table.BaseColumn$3.call(BaseColumn.java:122)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:578)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:563)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.updateItem(TableCell.java:644)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.indexChanged(TableCell.java:468)
    at javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:116)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.updateCells(TableRowSkinBase.java:523)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.init(TableRowSkinBase.java:147)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.<init>(TableRowSkin.java:64)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableRow.createDefaultSkin(TableRow.java:212)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:859)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9035)
    at javafx.scene.Node.applyCss(Node.java:9132)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.setCellIndex(VirtualFlow.java:1957)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCell(VirtualFlow.java:1790)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCellLength(VirtualFlow.java:1872)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.computeViewportOffset(VirtualFlow.java:2511)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.layoutChildren(VirtualFlow.java:1189)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1076)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:552)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit$$Lambda$308/27199650.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:313)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:340)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:525)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:505)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$400(QuantumToolkit.java:334)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$$Lambda$42/1903757175.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/658471308.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 39 more
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils
    at com.panemu.tiwulfx.table.BaseColumn$3.call(BaseColumn.java:135)
    at com.panemu.tiwulfx.table.BaseColumn$3.call(BaseColumn.java:122)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:578)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:563)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.updateItem(TableCell.java:644)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.indexChanged(TableCell.java:468)
    at javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:116)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.updateCells(TableRowSkinBase.java:523)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.init(TableRowSkinBase.java:147)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.<init>(TableRowSkin.java:64)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableRow.createDefaultSkin(TableRow.java:212)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:859)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1269)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1269)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1269)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:855)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9035)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9028)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9028)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Scene.java:545)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.access$3600(Scene.java:159)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2392)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit$$Lambda$308/27199650.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:313)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:340)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:525)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:505)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$400(QuantumToolkit.java:334)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$$Lambda$42/1903757175.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/658471308.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils
    at com.panemu.tiwulfx.table.BaseColumn$3.call(BaseColumn.java:135)
    at com.panemu.tiwulfx.table.BaseColumn$3.call(BaseColumn.java:122)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:578)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:563)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.updateItem(TableCell.java:644)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.indexChanged(TableCell.java:468)
    at javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:116)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.updateCells(TableRowSkinBase.java:523)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.init(TableRowSkinBase.java:147)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.<init>(TableRowSkin.java:64)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableRow.createDefaultSkin(TableRow.java:212)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:859)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1269)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1269)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1269)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:855)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9035)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9028)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9028)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Scene.java:545)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.access$3600(Scene.java:159)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2392)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit$$Lambda$308/27199650.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:313)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:340)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:525)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:505)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$400(QuantumToolkit.java:334)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$$Lambda$42/1903757175.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/658471308.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils
    at com.panemu.tiwulfx.table.BaseColumn$3.call(BaseColumn.java:135)
    at com.panemu.tiwulfx.table.BaseColumn$3.call(BaseColumn.java:122)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:578)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:563)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.updateItem(TableCell.java:644)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.indexChanged(TableCell.java:468)
    at javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:116)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.updateCells(TableRowSkinBase.java:523)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.init(TableRowSkinBase.java:147)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.<init>(TableRowSkin.java:64)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableRow.createDefaultSkin(TableRow.java:212)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:859)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1269)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1269)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1269)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:855)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9035)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9028)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9028)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Scene.java:545)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.access$3600(Scene.java:159)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2392)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit$$Lambda$308/27199650.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:313)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:340)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:525)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:505)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$400(QuantumToolkit.java:334)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$$Lambda$42/1903757175.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/658471308.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Do you have all your dependencies defined?  It can't find a class: Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils

Comment: you're correct, i forgot to add beans Utilis dependency to my pom.xml file